# Transposing rows to a single column

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a grid element which requires input values in a single column

```
 Key_id  event1    name1  date1   price1   event2   name2  date2   price2 
  234   Marriage   Sasha  09-DEC   4300   Birthday  Kate   10-DEC   3000
```

My SQL query output will return data listed in rows

```
Key_id  event     Name    date     price
 234   Marriage   Sasha  09-DEC    4300
 234   Birthday   Kate   10-DEC    3000
```

So i need to transpose or convert the list of rows to columns based on key_id.The values are not fixed and will be dynamic based on the time period selected by the user.

I have gone through similar questions in this forum , But i would like to know whether the same thing can be achieved using any Java API or SQL queries.

Kindly enlighten me on how to achieve this ..

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual RDBMS MySQL or Oracle? What do you mean by *transpose the list of rows **to a single column** based on id*. You showed 9 columns in desired output...

Comment: @ peterm Thanks for your reply..I am using Oracle ..The thing is my query output data will be listed as rows with repetitive key_id.I need a solution in such a way that the desired output should be grouped into a single column based on the key_id..

Comment: ... you still haven't cleared up what you mean by 'convert to a single column' - do you mean concatenate individual columns (event, name, etc) to a single one (note, I _don't_ recommend this, as you loose easy ways to separate the information).

Comment: @ Clockwork-Muse Sorry if my question wasn't clear. i need to transpose my rows to columns with id as the key , so that the data grows column wise..Hope this clears your question..Thanks

Comment: hi @jegadees was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I guess you want to transpose the horizontal axis (columns) into vertical.

Use something like:

```
select t.key_id
,      t.event1 event
,      t.name1  name
,      t.date1  date_event
,      t.price1 price
from   table t
union all
select t.key_id
,      t.event2 event
,      t.name2
,      t.date2
,      t.price2
from   table t
```

Did this help you? If so, please confirm. If not, please leave a note.